# Replacing '?' for a '*' in a pattern change the fact that if there is a match?

Tags: regex

I have to do a task, this task is add some functionality to a program that determines if a pattern exists in a text (both entered by keyboard).

The program that has been given to me can alredy determine if there is a match between a pattern that uses the character '*' (matches zero or more occurrences of the previous character) in a text. Now, one of the features that have been asked to add is to be able to use the character '?' in the pattern (there is zero or one of the preceding element).

**My question is:**
Because the program that I have to improve don't determine the location of the match, but will only determine if there is a match... I can consider the '?' as the character '*'?

I began to think, and I reached the conclusion that if a pattern has the '*' character, and that character is replaced by the '?', it won't change the fact that if there is a match or not.

What you think?, Am I right or not?

Comment: `? matches {0,1}` and `* matches {0,n}`. Neither must match anything. Both can match at least one of a thing - but the `*` can match many more times as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pattern with only one quantifier, and no text after it, it will work the same.

For an example where it won't work the same, the pattern `ba*h` will match the text `baaaaaaaaah`, but the pattern `ba?h` won't.